# UML: Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml

I need to create USE Case for the following component. 
Manage Consultant
Use cases--add consultant, update consultant, add speciality, update speciality Consultants and specialities are either active or inactive.

- Speciality is a stand alone class
- Speciality is also part of Consultant class 
  [image]

2nd Component 
Confirm appointment--consultant views appointments and confirms times. Firm appointment is saved and customer gets email confirming time.

Confirm Invoice--consultant views invoices and, if an invoice has been paid, marks as paid.
[image]

Am I right? 
From my understanding USE Case does not show the detailed list steps with in the USE Case. So mark paid you don't don't ned to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first diagram: do not use generalization with UCs. Each UC represents a unique single added value for the actor. If there were such a thing as a generalized added value that would never be unique. Remember: there's just a unique selling point, never a general one. Just remove the Manage-UCs and connect the "real ones" directly.

Your 2nd diagram looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for the help.